# i want to get GWA of the grades using sql. what will i do?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```sql
Create table StudentGrade
(
    CourseCode varchar(max), 
    CourseTitle Varchar(max), 
    Units int, Grade decimal(4,2)
);

Insert into StudentGrade (CourseCode, CourseTitle, Units, Grade)
values ('COSC1003', 'Data Structures and Algorithms', 3 , 1.50),

('GEDC1006', 'Readings in Philipine History', 3, 2.25),
('PHED1003', 'Physical Education 3', 2, 1.25),
('GEDC1014', 'Rizals Life and Works', 3, 1.50 ),

('COSC1007', 'Human-Computer interaction',3 ,1.25 ),
('INTE1044', 'Object Oriented Programming', 3, 1.75),
('COSC1001', 'Principles of Communication', 3 ,2.25),

('COSC1008', 'Platform Technology', 3 , 1.50)


Select Count(CourseCode) from StudentGrade
Select SUM(Units) from StudentGrade
Select Count (Grade) from StudentGrade where Grade < 2.00
Select Count (Grade) from StudentGrade where Grade > 2.00
```

this is my query

```
Select
    Units,
    Grade,
    ( sum(Units * Grade ) / sum(Units) ) as calculatedgrade
from StudentGrade
```

and I get the following error

> column 'StudentGrade.Units' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: i want to do is multiply units to grade then add all the answer then divide to the total units

Comment: Do you have a question? Just posting some SQL doesn't make a question. If you run your batch, however, the error is pretty clear ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6751e7ca1e7c87e4be2b176871962c8a)). What about said error don't you understand? What are your expected results here?

Comment: column 'StudentGrade.Units' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
this is the error. I'm new in SQL , I don't know if my queries is correct. i just want to get the general weighted average. the last line is my query to get gwa . did I miss some codes ?

Comment: Again, what about the error don't you understand? What are your expected results here?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have aggregate function and normal columns on the same line.

You need to modify query as below to get the GWA.

```sql
Select sum(Units * Grade ) / sum(Units) as calculatedgrade 
from StudentGrade
```

| calculatedgrade |
| --- |
| 1.673913 |

**UPDATE 1**
For rounding, you have to use [ROUND function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
Select ROUND(sum(Units * Grade ) / sum(Units),2) as calculatedgrade 
from StudentGrade
```

**UPDATE 2**
If you want to keep only two decimal places, you should cast it.

```sql
Select CAST(ROUND(sum(Units * Grade ) / sum(Units),2) as DECIMAL(3,2)) as calculatedgrade 
from StudentGrade
```

Comment: how to query so i can round off  the gwa  sir?

Comment: the output is 1.670000 how can i make this into 1.67 ?